# Alternative proof that $\ell^1$ is not reflexive using a hyperplane.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, consider $f\in X'$, $f\neq 0$, and $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$, where $X'$ is the dual space. Define $$H_{(f, \alpha)}:=\{x\in X:f(x)=\alpha\}.$$
Lemma 1: Suppose that $X$ is reflexive. Then there exists $z\in H_{(f,\alpha)}$ such that $\inf_{h\in H_{(f, \alpha)}}\lVert h \rVert = \lVert z \rVert$.
This was already proven, but is what we will use to show that $\ell^1$ is not reflexive.

Now consider the isometric isomorphism $$\phi:\ell^\infty\to(\ell^1)', \ \ \phi(x)(y):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n, \ x\in \ell^\infty, \ y\in \ell^1.$$
Let $x\in\ell^\infty$ be such that $\lVert x\rVert_\infty \notin \{\lvert x_k\rvert: k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and consider the hyperplane $H$ defined by $$H=H_{(\phi(x), \lVert x\rVert_\infty)}:=\{y\in \ell^1:\phi(x)(y)=\lVert x\rVert_\infty\}.$$

I would like to show that in the particular case when we consider $H=H_{(\phi(x), \lVert x\rVert_\infty)}$ as above that there does not exist an $y\in H$ such that $\inf_{h\in H} \lVert h \rVert = \lVert y \rVert$. This would show by Lemma 1 that the space $\ell^1$ is not reflective.

Now I already showed that for $x\in \ell^\infty$ that $\lVert x\rVert_\infty \leq \lVert \phi(x)\rVert \inf_{h\in H} \lVert h \rVert_1$. Now since $\phi$ is an isometry we have that $\lVert \phi(x)\rVert=\lVert x\rVert_\infty$. So $\inf_{h\in H}\lVert h\rVert_1\geq 1$. Now for the sake of contradiction suppose that there exists $z\in H$ such such that $\inf_{h\in H} \lVert h\rVert_1=\lVert z\rVert_1$, then $\lVert z\rVert_1\geq 1$. So we have that $\lVert x\rVert_\infty=\phi(x)(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n$. Thus $\lVert x\rVert_\infty=\lvert\phi(x)(z)\rvert=\lvert\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n z_n\rvert<\lVert x\rVert_\infty \lVert z\lVert_1$. Thus the inequality is a strict inequality, that is, $\lVert z \rVert_1 > 1$. Now I feel very confused because I would think that a contradiction would be quite straightforward to find, but I'm so far stuck on how to proceed.

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=\inf_{z\in H}\|z\|_1$.

if $z\in H$ then
$$\|x\|_\infty = \phi(x)(z)=|\phi(x)(z)|\le \|x\|_\infty\|z\|_1$$
so $1\le\|z\|_1$.  Hence $1\le M$.

For any $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$, there is some $n_0$ such that $|x_{n_0}|>\|x\|_\infty(1-\varepsilon)$.  Let $z=\frac{x_{n_0}\|x\|_\infty}{|x_{n_0}|^2}e_{n_0}$ where is $e_{n_0}$ is the standard basis vector at $n_0$.  Then
$$
\begin{split}
\phi(x)(z)=\overline{x_{n_0}}z_{n_0}=\overline{x_{n_0}}x_{n_0}\frac{\|x\|_\infty}{|x_{n_0}|^2}=\|x\|_\infty\\
\|z\|_1=\frac{|x_{n_0}|\|x\|_\infty}{|x_{n_0}|^2}=\frac{\|x\|_\infty}{|x_{n_0}|}<\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}
\end{split}
$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrarily small this proves that $M=1$.

By the lemma there is a $z\in H$ such that $\|z\|_1=M=1$ and $\phi(x)(z)=\|x\|_\infty$.  Let $m$ be such that $z_m\ne 0$.  Then
$$|\overline{x_m}z_m|=|\overline{x_m}||z_m|<\|x\|_\infty|z_m|$$
and for $n\ne m$
$$
|\overline{x_n}z_n|=|\overline{x_n}||z_n|\le\|x\|_\infty|z_n|
$$
hence
$$
|\phi(x)(z)|\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\overline{x_n}z_n|<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|x\|_\infty|z_n|=\|x\|_\infty\|z\|_1=\|x\|_\infty
$$
which contradicts $\phi(x)(z)=\|x\|_\infty$.$\Box$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have two questions tho'. Why is $\phi(x)(z)=\overline{x_{n_0}}z_{n_0}$? I suppose the overline means complex conjugate, but I don't understand how that equality came to be. And finally why does your last distinction between the case when $z_m\neq 0$ and $z_n$ matter if in the end you use the strict inequality to show the contradiction?

Comment: @Num2: 1) Because $z_{n_0}$ is the only non-zero coefficient of $z$ in the second paragraph ($z$ is a multiple of $e_{n_0}$).  2) The distinction is because for at least one coefficient $m$ we must have strict $<$ inequality, while for $n\ne m$ we only know $\le$.  This gives strict $<$ when summing over all $n$, including $n=m$.